# Handling I/O on 16-bit characters

Tags: java

Which one is used to handle I/O on 16-bit unicode characters in java - FileInputStream/FileOutputStream or Readers/Writers? What is the difference between them?

Comment: The javadoc exists for this specific reason.

Comment: Follow the link : http://math.hws.edu/javanotes/c11/s1.html

Comment: Input/OutputStreams operate on bytes. Readers/Writers interpret those bytes as characters and can deal with character encodings. It took me a long time to remember this at first for some reason; an easy way to remember is that you read books and write stories - those ones are for text.

Answer (score 1):

[InputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html)s provide raw bytes while [Reader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html)s provide chars.

You can wrap an InputStream with an [InputStreamReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) that interpretes the bytes as unicode characters according to the encoding you define.

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(..);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis, "utf8"));
```